# PyProcar band-structure plot error

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, python, pyprocar

I am getting the following error when trying to plot band-structure using PyProcar. I posted a comment in author's github page as well ([see at the bottom](https://github.com/romerogroup/pyprocar/issues/93)). In the meantime, I wonder if anyone could please help? Thanks.

P.S. Please note that, I was able to plot this same band-structure calculation using sumo-plot. I PyProcar has some additional functionalities (such as spin-projection) that sumo-plot doesn't have.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyprocar_band_spin.py", line 25, in <module>
    pyprocar.bandsdosplot(bands_file='PROCAR',
  File "/dartfs-hpc/rc/home/m/f00656m/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyprocar/scriptBandsDosplot.py", line 181, in bandsdosplot
    tick_labels = np.array(re.findall("!\s(.*)", KPmatrix[0]))
**IndexError: list index out of range**
```

Answer (score 4):

From their code, it looks like `KPmatrix = re.findall("reciprocal[\s\S]*", KPread)`, so it tries to grab everything from the word "reciprocal" to the end of `KPread` (the read in KPOINTS file.

As far as I can tell, the surrounding code doesn't do any processing of `KPread` prior to this point, so I think the fix may be as simple as writing "reciprocal" rather than "Reciprocal" in that line of your KPOINTS file.

If that works, you can mention it as a fix in the GitHub issue, though I should note the script you are using is listed in the repo under`pyprocar/v1/scripts` and there seems to be an updated script for later versions of PyProcar.

Comment: Thanks you so much! It really worked! Well, almost!! Now that I passed that hurdle I get the following error. Do you suggest I install PyProcar2 instead? [Initially I just did the simple pip install pyprocar following the website, so not sure if it's latest version] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZsDGP9UCT0oCkoidyFNa88YMh9i831x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know much about PyProcar, but I would say this sort of bug would in general tend to be fixed in later versions of a program. As to the new error you are getting, it seems to be that the code is finding 11 types of y values (based on it finding a shape of (11, 314)) while it finds only 10 different kinds of k-points (the values in `knames`). I'm not sure if that is another bug or something misformatted with your KPOINTS file that is causing it miss a `knames` value.